# Querying for all possible subparts of a part

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in an Access database, one containing parts and subparts and the other to store the relations between these part. The part relations table has a field for the parent part and another for the subpart. With these two tables, I can have subparts with subparts, subparts associated multiple parent parts, and (obviously) parent parts with multiple sub parts.

What I want to be able to do, using just a SQL statement, is bring up all of the subparts (and all of their subparts) of a single parent part. Is there a way to do this without putting any limits on how many levels deep of subparts the query can draw up?

Comment: You may be interested in http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ It is mysql, but it has a great deal that is relevant.

Comment: How many records are you talking about here?  VBA may be a bit tasked to do this for you

Comment: If hierarchies are central to your requirements, SQL Server Express has HierarcyID : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you'd have to do it in VBA.

Also, you could just have one table if you had a 'parentPartID' in your existing parts table.  If there's no parent, the value is null.